# While refreshing the page browser serving code for a moment

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have my own custom contact portlet. when i goes thru the portlet or refresh the page which contains the contact portlet for a while it displays the 'code'. I dont know why?
Please look at the image when i refresh the page it shows the code for a moment.

[image]

its just for a second and afterwards it displays the contacts.
[image]

My jsp is here:

```
<li class="media" ng-click="viewUser(u.id)" ng-repeat="u in list | filter:filterContacts" data-user-id="{{u.id}}" class="ng-cloak">
                <span class="col-lg-3">
                    <img alt="{{u.name}}" ng-src="{{u.portraitURL}}" class="media-object">
                </span>
                <span class="media-body col-lg-9">
                    <p>{{u.name}}</p>
                    <p>{{u.email}}</p>
                </span>
            </li>
```

Comment: Akash-can you check in browser console,if the angular js objects are populated by ng-controller list,before the page is loaded.Try putting a break point,as it seems,the data in object is populated post loading of DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that in the first screenshot it shows *Mes contacts, Rechercher* and in the second - *My Contacts, Search*. So probably something with the language? To me it looks like when you show those values - the correct language is not yet loaded, and after a second it is already there and everything is shown as expected. 
What do you use - JQuery, AUI? In such situation if I run any initialization scripts - I would run them in $(document).ready() or AUI().ready(), to make sure the page is loaded when the script starts.

Comment: Nope! everything is fine with language. sorry for mistake that i uploaded the image from different language. But the issue is still same. for a moment(1 sec) it displaying the code. afterwards it upload the contact.